# How do I destructure this JavaScript Object completely, It keeps returning Undefined yet there`s a value assigned to it

Tags: javascript, api, nested, javascript-objects, destructuring

I`m using selenium to webscrape a website that is renderd dynamically using JavaScript but I am not get the data I am looking for,
The initial data returned was an array of objects;

```
            [
              WebElement {
              driver_: thenableWebDriverProxy {
              session_: [Promise],
              executor_: [Executor],
              fileDetector_: null,
              onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
              then: [Function: bound then],
              catch: [Function: bound catch]
            },
          id_: Promise { '4c778b4e-64aa-4433-ad98-2d07e9f20c29' }
       },
```

Which I further opened into;

```
    thenableWebDriverProxy {
             session_: Promise {
                         Session {
                         caps_: [Capabilities]
                       }
                    },
             executor_: Executor {
                      w3c: true,
                      customCommands_: Map(4) {
                      'getContext' => [Object],
                      'setContext' => [Object],
                      'install addon' => [Object],
                      'uninstall addon' => [Object]
                   },
            log_: Logger {
                    name_: 'webdriver.http.Executor',
                   level_: null,
                   parent_: [Logger],
                   handlers_: null
               }
           },
          fileDetector_: null,
          onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
         then: [Function: bound then],
         catch: [Function: bound catch]
  }
```

And this again contiues into;

```
                    Promise {
                        Session {
                            id_: '4083ce6f-f536-41bd-9f4e-9c1a66c4486f',
                            caps_: Capabilities { map_: [Map] }
                       }
                    },
```

Now how do I get to the properties of caps_ that have been nested in there,
My code keeps returning `undefined` even when I test for the value of `id_` which should obviously return a value since I can see it even without writting any line of code.

Here's my code

```
                         let {Builder, By} = require('selenium-webdriver');
                            driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

                            (async function test(){

                            await driver.get('https://www.betika.com/');

                            let data = driver.findElements(By.css('.match'));

                             try{
                                  data.then(function(result) {
                                  console.log(result);
                                  
                                  const fine = result.forEach(element => { 
        
                                         console.log(element.driver_); 
                                  });

                                  const outPut = result.forEach(element => {
                                         console.log(element.
                                                     driver_.
                                                     session_);

                                  });

                           const Test = result.forEach(element => {
                              console.log(element.
                                    driver_.
                                    session_.
                                    caps_);

                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually "data" doens't work as a DOM tree, the library says that the return of function used in your code is a WebElement, so you can use to navigate or get information based on the search.

For exemple:

```
let { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');

driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

async function test() {

    await driver.get('https://yoursite/login');

    let data = await driver.findElement(By.css('label')).getText();

    console.log(data)
}

test();
```

Data result could be something like "E-mail" if the site has a structure like this:

```
<form>
<label>E-mail<input/><label>
<form>
```

Source: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/

Comment: Thanks for brining that up actually, I hadn`t noticed. Could you help me with the destructuring. That`s where I have the main problem

Comment: The problem is that this is not a regular object, all of the data you want , would be brought by the function once it is exectud, tha's why you shold use ```getText()```, for exemple. 
You could try to make a function that brings all the nested objects and then print all the function as strings, but I can't understand the point of doing it. I might be easier to read and understand the library it self.

Comment: Still returns ```undefined```

Comment: What is returning ```undefined```?
Try to edit your question telling us what you are trying to achieve with your code, because maybe you can use another tool to do that.

Comment: Owk, I just edited the question now

Comment: You have mistaken my comment as your answer, to avaluate what went wrong whit the getText() method we need the code you are trying to run, you can use tools like https://replit.com/ for that.